# Remove boost using brew and install specific version

Tags: macos, boost, homebrew

```
brew info boost
boost: stable 1.71.0 (bottled), HEAD
Collection of portable C++ source libraries
https://www.boost.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/boost.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: icu4c ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
Building of Boost.Log is disabled because it requires newer GCC or Clang.
==> Analytics
install: 31,607 (30 days), 109,724 (90 days), 590,627 (365 days)
install-on-request: 11,180 (30 days), 39,021 (90 days), 197,063 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)


brew --version
Homebrew 2.2.1
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 87d2; last commit 2019-12-16)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision cb1c4; last commit 2019-12-16)


brew uninstall boost
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/boost


brew remove boost
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/boost


brew install boost@1.59

Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
No changes to formulae.

Warning: boost@1.59 1.59.0 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 1.59.0, run `brew reinstall boost@1.59`


brew switch boost 1.59
Error: boost not found in the Cellar.


brew list | grep boost
boost@1.59
```

Why `brew info` shows 1.71.0 version?
Why I can't remove or uninstall boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `brew info` shows the last available version of boost which is 1.7.10. This is correct.

When you run `brew uninstall boost` or `brew remove boost`, Homebrew tries to remove the last version (1.7.10). Homebrew doesn't succeed because this version is not installed. This is correct.

You have installed the formula `boost@1.59`, which is a different formula from `boost`. You can remove it with `brew remove boost@1.59`, or obtain information on how to use it with `brew info boost@1.59`.